# Can I have my android app open a link to a web page?

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, http, url

I am developing an app in Android Studio which should open a web page on the phone using Google when a button is clicked. For example, when I have a button to open Google, Facebook and Twitter. I know there are apps for Google, Facebook and Twitter and the app could just link to them but not everyone has these apps and the web page can be loaded a lot easier. Is there a bit of code out there that can do this? Where the URL or http can be passed in and if the button is clicked the URL will open up in Google.

Comment: An url that opens in Google? Whats that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This peice of code will open up the default browser app with the url you specify

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

You'll need to have the permission to access the browser in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your resonance.